# Can't run the command on NPM command line(Windows) to work with image-picker

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm very new to react-native.

Error

> Failed to get dependency config.

Run `CLI with --verbose` flag for more details. when I'm trying to run react-native link react-native-image-picker

I've tried installing with
yarn add react-native-config and googled and hardly found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of react native are you using? and are you using expo ? if yes then you cant link the libraries , you have to use expo image picker to implement the image pick functionality.  [Expo image picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)

Comment: I'm using expo and figured out that I can't link. Thanks!